# JavaScript SQL injection protection for array/list

Tags: javascript, arrays, sql-injection

I know I need to escape all input given from the user before I use it in SQL query, e.g.

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` =" + connection.escape(req.params.id);`
```

BUT, how can I do when the input is an array of values? for example, `user_id`s I need to delete?

This is how I do it now, but it's not safe:

```
var sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id IN (" + itemIDs.toString() + ")";
```

How to prevent SQL injection?

Comment: Which server side programming language you are using and which database it is (MySQL)?

Comment: toString looks like Java? Unless you're sending the *query* with an AJAX call...which is just scary.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann `var` isn't Java, though

Comment: Just pass the Id's into your server side code.. then typecast the Id's into int or any related data type that suits you and then use it in your query.